# Aws elastic beanstalk cli setup on Mac

Tags: xcode, macos, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am trying to install aws elastic beanstalk cli on my mac machine. In the [prerequisites](https://github.com/aws/aws-elastic-beanstalk-cli-setup) it says that Python requires following:

```
Xcode openssl zlib readline
```

But, on running the command, I get:

```
-bash: Xcode: command not found
```

How am I suppose to install this?

Comment: Have you installed Xcode on your mac?

Comment: I have xcode on my machine already

Comment: It seems that for some reason `Xcode` can't be found. Have you tried with absolute path to `Xcode`?

Answer (score 0):

An alternative solution is to run the aws cli inside a docker container. It will eliminate the possible issues which may be caused by the OS/library upgrading in the future.